# Azure IoT Edge API module cannot be accessed . Request timed out

Tags: python, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I'm implementing API on azure IoT edge runtime installed on a Ubuntu hyper-v VM.
I have a flask API module implemented and up and running in the edge runtime on Ubuntu vm.
So i have a requirement to access this API from the host machine which is my local machine running on windows 10. IP address the API module running on is http://172.20.36.197:5000/predict.

this works in the guest(Ubuntu hyper-v VM) machine but request times out every time i try to invoke this call in host machine. I have disabled even the firewalls of host VM. But no luck. seems I have to access the IoT edge runtime running on Ubuntu VM from my host machine.

I just ran the same flask API in a docker container not within the IoT edge runtime as an edge module but within docker inside Ubuntu Hyper-v VM and i can access that API with from the host without any issue. Following is my code for flask API edge module running on IoT edge runtime

```
import os
from azure.iot.device.aio import IoTHubModuleClient
from flask import Flask

port =int(os.environ.get("port",5000))
print("port is ",port)

# Initialize flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

# Create an endpoint
@app.route('/predict')
def predict_chiller_condition():
    print("api func called")
    predictedVal=3
    return 'predicted value is '+str(predictedVal)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=port)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is struggling to solve such a scenario, you should expose your edge module container running on a guest VM by adding `ExposedPorts` in `createOptions` section in deployment.template.json as following. And also IPv4 address of the VM should be used with the relevant port.

```
        "modules": {
        "test_flask_api": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "type": "docker",
        "status": "running",
        "restartPolicy": "always",
        "settings": {
          "image": "${MODULES.test_flask_api}",
          "createOptions": {
            "ExposedPorts": {
              "5000/tcp": {}
            },
            "HostConfig": {
              "PortBindings": {
                "5000/tcp": [
                  {
                    "HostPort": "5000"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```